# Mysql error : Error Code: 126. Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_52e_0.MYI'; try to repair it

Tags: mysql, tmp

When i running below query it gives me error as
`Error Code: 126. Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_52e_0.MYI'; try to repair it`

Query:

```
Select id, first_name, last_name, communication_email,birthday,group_concat(email_template_id) as T from uzer
LEFT join user_email_preference ON uzer.id = user_email_preference.user_id    
group by user_id limit 1
```

When i removed `group_concat()` funciton from query it runs perfectly without error, dont know why?

I google with error and found that if you don't have enough in `tmp/` than only it give this type of error. But i fetching only one reord here and moreover when I have `group_concat()` in query than only it gives me error.

Answer (score 0):

try to

```
"REPAIR TABLE `uzer`"
```

and 'user_email_preference'

more detail: [mysql repair](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/repair-table.html)

Comment: as per error tmp/ folder is full. I already empty folder, eventhough it is giving me the error.

Comment: can you re-create your tmp/ directory ?

Answer (score 0):

Error 126 is an application runtime error. Usually this error occurs while an application tries to regain the information from a specific DLL file but this file does not exist anymore on your computer.

- Recover missing or deleted DLL File
- Expand DLL file image from Windows 7 Installation disc
- Repair Windows Registry with Reginout or Ccleaner
- Register again the DLL File
- Delete Registry entry related to SQL Server
- Uninstall and reinstall the concerned program

Thanks